# Blocking functions from being called directly in Bash

Tags: bash

So, I'm working on a function that has helper functions that, if called directly, could potentially cause problems or do nothing.

What I want to do is ensure that these functions will *only* execute if they are being called by the main function.

Here's a couple sample functions I came up with to illustrate the problem:

```
function testfunc() { echo "Main function:  ${FUNCNAME[@]}" ; sleep 2 ; subfunc ; }
function subfunc() { [[ ${FUNCNAME[1]} =~ ^testfunc$ ]] && echo "Sub Function: ${FUNCNAME[@]}" || echo "Can't be called directly. :< ${FUNCNAME[@]}" ; }
```

So, it's using the FUNCNAME environment variable: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html

It works perfectly fine as long as the previous function exits normally:

```
$ testfunc
Main function:  testfunc
Sub Function: subfunc testfunc

$ subfunc
Can't be called directly. :< subfunc
```

The problem arises when a function is Ctrl+C'd.  It stays in the FUNCNAME variable indefinitely:

```
$ testfunc
Main function:  testfunc
^C

$ subfunc
Sub Function: subfunc testfunc

$ subfunc
Sub Function: subfunc testfunc
```

This is driving me crazy.  I tried using the 'caller' built in and had the same results and it appears to be pulling information based on the FUNCNAME variable.

There are several tricks I could use to do what I'm wanting... adding an argument that the subfunction checks for, setting a variable that the subfunction checks for, obscuring the function name and aliasing the function and calling it from the main function... etc.

These can all be gotten around though, and I want to make sure that it's only being called after the main function has run and all the proper variables have been set.

Hopefully someone can shed some light on this for me, or point me toward a method of doing what I'm trying to do.  This feels like it might be a bug with the FUNCNAME variable in Bash, maybe. :<

Thanks, all. :)

Comment: Cannot reproduce; my `bash` sticks to the docs ("This variable exists only when a shell function is executing"). Ctrl-C clears it.

Comment: @Amadan : That's odd.  What version are you using?  I've tried on:

GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin14)

GNU bash, version 4.2.37(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

GNU bash, version 4.3.11(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

Comment: Reproduced in Ubuntu (via ssh), where Ctrl-C kills the function. In OSX, Ctrl-C kills sleep, and `testfunc` ends normally; that might be why I couldn't reproduce it. EDIT: I see you tested on Apple too, so no idea why it's different. Mine is 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin14) as well...

Comment: @Amadan I dunno then.  The TESTFUNC variable is retaining the Ctrl+C'd function for me on 3 different versions, apparently. One OSX, two Ubuntu.  I wonder if there's some other environment variable/setting that's messing with me.  Goin to pore over my .bash_profile/.bashrc and env variables for now.

Comment: For now, I have a kinda-fix.  I just alias all the functions like so:  `alias testfunc='declare -a FUNCNAME=() && testfunc'` ; Not ideal, but it works.  I'd love to know why this variable persists in my environment even though it's invisible in `env` output. :/

Comment: As to your last question, [`bash` source](http://savannah.gnu.org/git/?group=bash) has `make_funcname_visible(int on_or_off)`. But yeah, it seems it's not properly cleaned up. I am not familiar enough with the source to say why not, and I don't have enough time to debug it myself. `execute_cmd.c` might be a good place to look.

Answer (score 0):

Use `trap`

```
trap func_to_handle_crtlc 2

func_to_handle_crtlc()
{
  # code to handle control+c
  ...
}
```

The only issue with this is if you actually want to `exit` the script, you'll have to think of something :)

Comment: Yeah, I was using trap before, but trap is really janky if you're calling the function from terminal after it has been sourced.  Exiting for example will close your terminal.  I think the problem was that I was sourcing the functions then calling them directly, which was causing the variable to remain persistent between function calls because of how bash expands functions.  ¯\(°_o)/¯   I said screw it and added an alias for the script instead of sourcing it.